# Let a mean calculated for a specific group within a year to pertain to all groups in that given year

Tags: r, mean

I apologise for my poor formulation of a title. It reasonably resembles how I was having trouble finding similar/related questions prior to posting this question.
If a similar question have already been asked, and for which a sufficient answer have been provided, please let me know.

**My question is as follows:**

I have generated a variable, `VarX_mean`, which calculates the average of `VarX` across groups: `Year` and `Group2`, using the following code:

```
setDT(df)[, VarX_mean := mean(VarX), by = c("Year","Group2")]
```

Subsequently, I have replaced the VarX_mean for Group2==0 with 0's, `VarX_mean2`.

**What I wish to create**: 
I actually would like, is for the `VarX_mean` calculated for `Group2` to pertain to the whole year, i.e. column: `WhatIWishtoCreate`

```
    Year   Group2   VarX   VarX_mean  VarX_mean2    WhatIWishtoCreate
    2001     1        2      3          3             3
    2001     1        3      3          3             3
    2001     1        4      3          3             3
    2001     0        6      6          0             3
    2002     1        5      5.5        5.5           5.5
    2002     1        6      5.5        5.5           5.5
    2002     0        9      9          0             5.5
    2002     0        9      9          0             5.5
    2002     0        9      9          0             5.5
    2003     1        1      2.5        2.5           2.5
    2003     1        2      2.5        2.5           2.5
    2003     1        4      2.5        2.5           2.5
    2003     1        3      2.5        2.5           2.5
    2003     0        4      4          0             2.5
    2003     0        4      4          0             2.5
```

Thank you in advance.
Kind regards

Comment: With `dplyr` you can do `group_by(Year) %>% arrange(Group2) %>% mutate(WhatIWishtoCreate = first(VarX_mean)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
    group_by(Year) %>% 
    arrange(Group2) %>% 
    mutate(WhatIWishtoCreate = first(VarX_mean)
```

Comment: Thank you, Matt. I don't know if this approach is necessarily any better than the other suggested solutions, but it was the first answer to my question (originally as a comment to my question) and it solved my problem, so I marked your answer 'accepted'.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the `first` `VarX_mean` in each `Year` where `Group2 == 1`.

```
library(data.table)

df[, newcol := first(VarX_mean[Group2 == 1]), Year]
df

#    Year Group2 VarX VarX_mean VarX_mean2 newcol
# 1: 2001      1    2       3.0        3.0    3.0
# 2: 2001      1    3       3.0        3.0    3.0
# 3: 2001      1    4       3.0        3.0    3.0
# 4: 2001      0    6       6.0        0.0    3.0
# 5: 2002      1    5       5.5        5.5    5.5
# 6: 2002      1    6       5.5        5.5    5.5
# 7: 2002      0    9       9.0        0.0    5.5
# 8: 2002      0    9       9.0        0.0    5.5
# 9: 2002      0    9       9.0        0.0    5.5
#10: 2003      1    1       2.5        2.5    2.5
#11: 2003      1    2       2.5        2.5    2.5
#12: 2003      1    4       2.5        2.5    2.5
#13: 2003      1    3       2.5        2.5    2.5
#14: 2003      0    4       4.0        0.0    2.5
#15: 2003      0    4       4.0        0.0    2.5
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also do

```
library(data.table)
df[, newcol := VarX_mean[Group2 == 1][1], Year]
```